# What exactly are Integral Types?

Tags: c#, .net, types

Having studied the [switch documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.71).aspx) and discovering it can only switch on ***integral types*** I set about looking for a definition.  I can't find one anywhere. I can only [find a list of integral types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx).

I could take a guess that integral types are the types which are integrated into the language, however I'd be happier with a proper definition.  Does anyone have one?

Comment: Not all types that are integrated into the language are integral (System.Type, object...). Basically a type is integral if it's on the list of integral types - a tautological definition, but nonetheless true.

Comment: @SWeko: In this context [integral](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=integral) means "of or denoted by an integer", not "built-in".

Comment: @configurator: yes, and that's exactly what I'm saying in the comment.

Comment: @SWeko: My definition wasn't tautological though. A type is integral if it is a type of integer; it is impossible to define your own integer type, therefore the types of integer are sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong.

Comment: @Configurator: System.Numeric.BigInteger is an integer, and yet, it's not a valid switch expression.

Comment: @SWeko: It represents an integer, but it isn't an integer itself; it's a struct with lots of stuff in it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

"Integral" refers to *integer* types (i.e. whole numbers). In C# this means types like `int`, `long`, `short`, etc.

Please see [Integral Types Table (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/integral-types-table):

> The following table shows the sizes and ranges of the integral types, which constitute a subset of simple types.

**Edit:** Keep in mind that the `switch` statement supports literal strings as well.

Comment: How can I test for true / false in a switch statement then?  It seems to be neither integral nor a string and there isn't an implicit conversion for it.

Comment: @m.edmondson: I am not sure if I understand the problem. Are you trying to test whether or not a type is integral at execution time?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why I can do this: switch (true)
            {
                case false:
                    actual = "false";
                    break;
                case true:
                    actual = "true";
                    break;
            }

Comment: @m.edmondson: Ok, I see what you mean. I guess you could say that you could chalk this up to bad documentation. MSDN should say that you can provide a boolean expression (because the compiler does allow it). I think the reason that it was omitted was because this is an edge case and not very useful (since your example would be much better expressed with an `if` statement).

Comment: @Andrew Hare - Very confusing I think and the documentation is certainly misleading.  I think switch(true) does have its uses as it tends to be more readable and succinct than a load of elseif which muddy the solution

Comment: @m.edmondson could you expand on what you mean by 'a load of elseif' ? A `switch` on a `bool` can only have two `case` s!

Comment: @AakashM: I don't think this is precisely true, actually.  See comment by Anders Dalvander on Eric's blog on [switch oddities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/13/four-switch-oddities.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments).  One hopes that there is no production code which relies on this.

Comment: @AndrewHare I understand that Int, long, short are integral type. So, what's the type of float and double?

Comment: [This](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_032.HTM) is a C spec, but I think it helps clear things up. An integral type is anything that is *represented* by an integer. This includes regular integer types, but also booleans (usually 1 or 0), characters (usually their integer ascii value), and sometimes string literals (array of chars so an array of integers essentially). `true` is a boolean in this case, making it an integral type.

Comment: @thatWiseGuy what is literal string?

Comment: I agree with @Cole said. integer types is value that **can be represent as** integer types

Answer (score 12):

The documentation you are studying was written in 2003 and is not up-to-date for the latest version of the language. I suggest that you stop studying the archive of the 2003 documentation and instead read the 2010 documentation if you are using a more modern version of C#.

The definitive reference that answers your question is the C# specification section 8.7.2, a portion of which I reproduce for your convenience here.

---

> The governing type of a switch
>   statement is established by the switch
>   expression.
>
> • If the type of the
>   switch expression is sbyte, byte,
>   short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong,
>   bool, char, string, or an enum-type,
>   or if it is the nullable type
>   corresponding to one of these types,
>   then that is the governing type of the
>   switch statement.
>
> • Otherwise,
>   exactly one user-defined implicit
>   conversion must exist from the
>   type of the switch expression to one
>   of the following possible governing
>   types: sbyte, byte, short, ushort,
>   int, uint, long, ulong, char, string,
>   or,  a nullable type corresponding to
>   one of those types.
>
> • Otherwise, if
>   no such implicit conversion exists, or
>   if more than one such implicit
>   conversion exists, a compile-time
>   error occurs.

---

Answer (score 4):

The sense of 'integral' being used here is the one in section 1 subsection b sub-sub-section 1 (!) at http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integral :

> being, containing, or relating to one or more mathematical integers